# Word for “all the groups an item belongs to”?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

To expand on the title slightly: all of the groups to which an item belongs *directly or indirectly*? That seems to make "parent groups," my first choice, ill-fitting.

The key concept here is membership, but that term generally refers to the items in the group, not the groups themselves.

#### A bit more explanation:

An item's relationship to a group may be direct or indirect because groups are hierarchical. The term would describe all of the relevant groups in the hierarchy.

#### An example:

Fuji is an apple. Apples are fruit. Fuji belongs to apples and fruit.

The phrase I need to construct is along the lines of: *Fuji and "the groups to which it belongs."*

#### Edit

As Barrie pointed out, my example involves categorical relationship, but that won't necessarily be the type of membership I'm referring to. The membership is arbitrary and changeable.

#### Edit 2

My example caused more confusion than good. The best metaphor for what I'd like to express is: a child has *parents* and *grandparents*, who are collectively his **ancestors**. I want to say: a user has *groups* and *(super?) groups*, which are collectively *_***?**_.

Comment: Perhaps _roles_?

Comment: That makes me think of "responsibilities," not necessarily membership. In that sense, it seems like an alternative to "groups," not a narrowing of its definition.

Comment: The fact that some categorisation schemas are hierarchical doesn't mean membership of any given higher-level category is "indirect". I'm English, but it's nonsense to suggest I'm only *indirectly* British.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In some cases this is a relevant distinction: the difference between parent and grandparent, for example. Incidentally, I already mentioned the membership is not categorical.

Comment: Category/supercategory? Some idea of the context would be helpful, since there may be specific terms that would help (species/genus, for example).

Comment: @JeffSahol: Sure. I was trying to keep it general, but this immediately applies to security groups. A user may belong to groups, which also belong to other groups, and so on.

Comment: Sorry, no help here. It is hard to say how to express this without using an expression like you used in the question ("directly or indirectly").

Comment: The concept of "transitive closure" or "reachability" may apply here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For parent-child relationships, *ancestor* works, or *ancestor groups* if you need to be explicit. An ancestor is a parent or parent of an ancestor. You could also use *containing*, *inclusive*, or maybe *superordinate*.

Comment: And then descendents, being the flip side.

Comment: _Containing group_ may be the best we can do. _Super-group_ is another one, although it reminds me of _[Cream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cream_(band))_. _Ancestor_ feels too specific for my use.

Answer (score 3):

The closest you’re going to get is probably *supersets*.

Answer (score 3):

[*Hypernyms*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy).

*Fuji* is a hyponym of *apple*. *Apple* is a hyponym of *fruit*. But *Fuji* is also a hyponym of *fruit*. And *fruit* and *apple* are both hypernyms of *Fuji*.

Comment: I considered suggesting this, but it didn’t seem to fit the question.

Comment: This was my first thought, too. By hypernym refers to the relationship between words, while the question is about the relationship between the objects that the words represent.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what context you have in mind, but in some cases *set* might be the word you need.

Comment: Perhaps I need to elaborate on this in the question, but groups sometimes belong to other groups, therefore the item belongs to some groups directly, and other groups indirectly.

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of hyponymy, in which ‘fruit’ is the superordinate of ‘apples’ and ‘apples’ is the superordinate of ‘Fuji’. Looked at in the other direction, ‘Fuji’ is a hyponym of ‘apples’, and ‘apples’ is a hyponym of ‘fruit’.

Comment: No. That's an idiosyncrasy of my example. The key idea is membership, but not necessarily categorical.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that, Daniel? Maybe by giving an example.

Comment: I edited my question to include a better example.

Comment: Along with supersets and subsets.

Answer (score 2):

You could refer to all broader categories containing the item as **classifications** of the item.

When sorting/labeling items, you would classify each based on certain characteristics relative to the sorting. Using the term classifications, therefore, would be relevant to any level of the heirarchy being discussed at the time.

**Edit**:
Based on the comments on this answer, I see no reason why the word **groups** would be insufficient.

Comment: As I've noted in comments and in the _Edit_ portion of my answer, the relationships are not categorical. In retrospect, I chose a poor example as it seems to be gaining more attention than the question and subsequent clarifications.

Comment: Could you provide an example of some of these arbitrary memberships?

Comment: Yes. Security groups. A user may belong to any number of groups, which themselves may belong to other groups, and so on. The term would refer to all the groups to which a user belongs, directly or indirectly.

Comment: In that case, I think *roles* would be a good candidate. It's essentially the purpose it serves in computer user permissions.

Comment: Either that or you would have to provide a name for each of these groups independently of members, and simply refer to them as that.

Comment: Role seems to be a synonym for group and, in that case, does little to express the idea of direct and indirect membership. I'm hoping this term would refine (or describe a relationship to) "group."

Comment: I think you would have to clarify the direct/indirect issue on a group-by-group basis. Either that or encompass both of them by omitting "(in)direct".

Comment: The best metaphor for what I'd like to express is: a child has parents and grandparents, who are collectively his _ancestors_. I want to say: a user has groups and (super?) groups, which are collectively __.

Comment: OK I see, that makes it much clearer. I suggest editing that into your question, although "groups" is still a generic enough word to work.

Answer (score 1):

A group (or kind or concept or class) that belongs to another group is a subgroup or child group and the larger including group is the supergroup or parent group. Extending this to more and more inclusive groups, one then calls them all:

> **ancestors**.

Comment: Perhaps ancestors is the right word. Is there a related word that implies a more temporal (or configurable) relationship? I think of ancestor as being _fixed_.

Answer (score 1):

"Associations" seems to fit nicely.

Comment: Ooh, I like it. _Associated groups_ is nice and general, and leaves open the exact closeness of the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Programmers, and perhaps some mathematicians, would use the word *class*.  "Apples" constitute a class.  "Fuji" would be a member of the "Apple" class.  "Apple" would be a member of the "Fruit" class.  "Fruit" may be referred to as the parent class or the *superclass* of "Apple".  "Fuji" is a *subclass* of "Apple".  Members of a class automatically belong to that class's superclass.

Answer (score 0):

The question reminds me of junior high math — sets and subsets.

Answer (score 0):

Another good one is domain. Fuji is within the *domain* of fruit.

Answer (score 0):

The area of overlap on a Venn diagram is referred to as the "intersection" and illustrates visually the groups which a given object belongs to. While typically used for a small number of groups due to the limitations of drawing numerous circles, there is no reason that large numbers of other figures couldn't be used to represent the groups if it was more conducive to understanding. A Wikipedia link which may help follows...
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram