# Not a synonym, but what?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, etymology

I am looking for a word that describes the relationship between two words that are not the same, are not used in lieu of the other, but are related in what they refer to.

Example, *storm/monsoon*. While *monsoon* may be substituted for *storm* occasionally, in a rather understated way, *storm* would not normally be substituted for *monsoon*.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, whether it’s suggestions or the information that no such word exists.

Comment: "Related" is good enough.

Comment: Note that there is always a *degree* of synonymy.

Comment: "Absolute synonyms display an optimum degree of synonymy while partial synonyms display varying degrees thereof. [Hartmann: books.google.com/books?isbn=0859894843]

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21335/14666

Answer (score 3):

> **[Hypernym](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hypernym)**

A hypernym is a more general case of a specific case. A monsoon is a kind of storm, but a storm is not a particular case of a monsoon. So 'storm' is a hypernym of 'monsoon'.

Comment: see also [groups to which an item belongs](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45782/word-for-all-of-the-groups-to-which-an-item-belongs)

Comment: +1 and this also means that "monsoon" and "storm" *are* synonyms. A hypernym is a kind of synonym. Synonyms have similar meanings, but it is not necessary that they always be interchangeable.

Comment: The kind of things the OP means to ask about seem more like siblings than hierarchies to me.

Comment: I wouldn't think that "synonym" is a hypernym of "hypernym". :-) The conventional understanding of synonyms is that they have similar meanings, not a sub/super relationship. Sure, synonyms don't have to mean EXACTLY the same thing, there are shades of meaning and degrees of synonymousness. Like "big" and "large" are virtually interchangeable. I just found a list of synonyms that included "important" and "vital". I'd say, well, sort of. Depending on context, understanding of degree, etc. But "animal" is a hypernym of "Scottish terrier", and I don't think anyone would say that they are synonyms.

Comment: @Jay: but 'antonym' is the antonym of 'synonym'. And really they're all very closely related.